# Does there exist any version of `INotifyPropertyChanged` for multiple changes?

Tags: c#, .net, inotifypropertychanged

I read about *Observer* pattern in the [GoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) book.

.Net Framework contains the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Has .Net Framework the similar interface but for notifying about changing of *the set* of properties instead of notifying about each property changed (*for increase in productivity*)?

I created such interface `INotifySubjectChanged` for my application (its event argument contains the set of changed properties) but maybe .Net Framework already has it and I invented a bicycle.

I published my simple code source on Bitbucket.org [here](https://bitbucket.org/Andrey-Bushman/observer). It maybe more clear what I want to do.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is a good question and I wonder why it was downvoted. Maybe someone knows a more definitive answer, but the only thing I can think of is using `INotifyPropertyChanged` for *all* properties.

Comment: Just for clarification reasons: How is the designer of a class supposed to trigger the event, when (s)he doesn't know the set of properties to be changed? Shouldn't this be handled by calling a method that is setting all the properties and triggering the final flush?

Comment: Even if you could, just exactly how does one set multiple properties simultaneously for this interface to be useful?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, my abstract class has the base implementation. Also it defines the protected method `OnPropertyChanged`. Nested classes are to call this method when their property was changed. I can publish the "Hello world" sample on *Bitbuket.org* if it is interesting for you. It works fine. But my question was about other...

Comment: @AndreyBushman ney, I am struggeling with the concept you are trying to implement: how can you trigger a set, when you don't know the set ...

Comment: Maybe you are looking for INotifyCollectionChanged (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @MickyD, it allows to me to edit the observer once only (for increase in productivity) instead to do many changes for each changing of subject's property.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, I know the set because the eventargs item contains their names.

Comment: @AndreyBushman sorry, still not pushing the point ... Say that a consumer sets property `A` and `B`, how does the emit-engine know that the consumer is done setting properties (as there is property `C` as well)? How does the emit-engine know, that a sequence is an *atomic*-operation and certain settings should be grouped together?

Comment: @vtortola, thank you, but my class is not a collection. Also `INotifyCollectionChanged` doesn't allow to me to know the names of the changed properties.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, I made it through a nested class. It implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: @AndreyBushman I should have been more specific: I cannot imagine how that should work in general except with hacks, as you are trying to encapsulate certain `set`-operations in one atomic operation. There might be helpers for this available, but I just don't get the point. Shouldn't you rather be designing additional classes and setting instances to one property instead of having multiple properties forming an entity?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, I added the code sample screen and its result into my topic. Maybe it will be more clear for you. Look it, please.

Comment: @AndreyBushman thanks for clearing that up. What you are doing is essentially creating a block/scope with `using` to define an atomic operation - one could also implement `user.DoneSettingStuff()` to emit an event. The point is that you explicitly need to create such a block - otherwise no emitting will take place (which is a bad thing eventually - how can you guarantee that every consumer uses `using`). Additionally, the usage of `GetNotificator` is not that intuitive. Nevertheless, I believe that you came up with a practicable solution to your problem.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, my English is bad. It may be mysimple code will be more clear for you. My code works without problem and notifies me through the way which I expected in my client.

Comment: Another problem, which you will not solve: When you are binding your `User`-entity, there is no creation of a block/scope with `using (....GetNotificator())` - therefore your code won't work with eg WPF. Anyway, I believe that this is a specific problem you are trying to solve and is not captured in the .NET framework (which has a more generic approach)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, the `GetNotificator()` allows to increase the speed of the operation of observer which is updated when the subject has many changed properties. It will be documented in my documentation. Also "old way" through the `INotifyPropertyChanged` works also. Therefore, even if developer knows nothing about the `GetNotificator()` method he can use `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The result will be the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123252/discussion-between-andreas-niedermair-and-andrey-bushman).

Comment: What benefit does this give over notifying for an individual property. Seems like it just adds complexity where none is needed.

Answer (score 4):

MSDN states that leaving the property name blank implies that all of the properties on the object have changed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

> The PropertyChanged event can indicate all properties on the object have changed by using either null or String.Empty as the property name in the PropertyChangedEventArgs.

Which is probably as close as you could get to what you are asking for from the .NET framework. Note that using this incorrectly and calling it when a smaller number of properties have changed might actually reduce performance in certain situations.

For record if the object is a collection (which you said it is not) you could leverage INotifyCollectionChanged.

If you are concerned about performance and efficiency, I'd first make sure that you actually are having performance issues and that the notification of changes is causing those performance issues.

If you are not concerned about your implementation working with WPF data binding and it is relatively clear as to its behavior, then I don't see anything wrong with the custom interface and event.

Comment: Essentially, this boils down to use a block (with `using`), which calls `OnPropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangdEventArgs(null))` upon disposal?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I'm not sure yet what the using block is for so I can't answer that.  You would want to call this after the changes have been complete.  If you had scenarios where you still wanted individual INotifyPropertyChange events for some of those properties you might also want to suppress those events during this "set" change.

Comment: Creating a disposable instance and wrapping the emitting in its `Dispose`-method is just another way of calling `user.StuffDone()`, except creating an explicit scope :)

Comment: I published my simple code source on Bitbucket.org and added the link into my topic. It maybe more clear what I want to do.